# Is a letter of recommendation from a member of defense committee helpful and acceptable?

Tags: postdocs, recommendation-letter

I am an assistant professor in a developing country. Previously, in 2019, I graduated from a university in my home city. In my Ph.D., I was able to publish 3 JCR papers with impact factors 6 or greater. One of my papers was published in a prestigious journal with If 11.5. My supervisor does not have any papers in such prestigious journals. I got my grade of 20 out of 20 from the defense committee which is very rare in this university.

My supervisor didn't even look at any of my work during all of my Ph.D. years ( eight years of hard work). He submitted a plagiarized paper to the same journal in which I submitted my hard work during the time my paper was under second time review. And the journal rejected them because of plagiarization at the start of the process. Anyway, our relationship became very bad afterward.

Now, I want to apply for the postdoctoral program in the US, Canada, or Europe, somewhere that I can improve my knowledge and expertise.
I don't want to ask him for a letter of reference. I asked a professor from my Ph.D. defense committee and he is willing to write a letter of recommendation.

My question is: Is a letter of reference from a professor who was a member of the Ph.D. defense committee useful? Someone who read and asked questions during my Ph.D. defense.

Comment: It's impossible to give advice in your particular situation without knowing much more about it than you can provide here.

The general principle for letters of recommendation is to have them from people who know your work well.

Comment: Knowing much more about what?

Comment: To give advice we'd need to know how well this reader knows your work,who  your other references are, how competitive a program you are applying to, why the plagiarism seemed to affect your paper. You should probably consult other faculty at your school for advice.